# Execute shortcode that is inside of post's the_content() when loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm loading a post via Ajax using `$.ajax();` from a script that is localized (to pass the ajax admin url over, etc) and the post content is ouputted using the standard `the_content();` method, and it all works great, except that shortcodes inside the post content loaded via ajax are not executed, they are rendered as [someshortcode].

Is there any way to make that shortcode be executed when the post is loaded via ajax + the PHP method gives Ajax the post content data via `the_content()`?

Comment: Use $content=apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); to send content data.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success running do_shortcode() on the content, then passing that return value to apply_filters().

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$content = do_shortcode(get_post_field( 'post_content', $postid ));
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $content;
```